# How can I elaborate this fairly complex regex to validate names

Tags: c#, regex

I want to add a temporary regex to validate names. The rules are :only a-z A-z and spaces are allowed. The name must be more than 3 letters and have one space in this case. Also it cannot have two spaces in line (one after the other). I don't care about spaces in the beginning or end of the string because I can trim them. Only the first word can be a single letter, the others must be two or more. Excuse me if some rule contradicted another, it is very difficult to formulate this question.

```
ed_vu (valid)

edd_v (invalid) the second word is one character (must be two or more)

e_lui (valid)

e_li (valid) 

e_ei_ed (valid) even though it has two spaces it has more than 4 letters
```

More examples

```
e_el_ed__uuu (invalid) two spaces in line

e_el_elld_liid_eiii_idid (valid)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

[`/^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]{2,})*$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/BGwRnp/3/)

Note: these flags are not necessarily what you need (they're useful for the example though).

Comment: that "/" is a regex delimiter? What is the "gm". I am using C# it doesn't need delimiters.

Comment: Those are called modifiers and are pretty standard. I'm not too familiar with C# but a quick Google gives me [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options).

Comment: And yes `/` is a delimiter and is not always needed depending on the language. This is really basic regular expression knowledge though.

Comment: @Jeto you should clarify a language when answering regex questions unless they are general regex questions (not usually the case)

Comment: @DiegoAlves `new Regex("regex here", RegexOptions.Multiline)`

Comment: @ctwheels Right. I figured this one was straightforward enough to be "portable" to any language though.

Comment: @Jeto it is, just post the raw regex and add a note to let the OP know to enable the multiline flag

Comment: Even though it is not covering all the requirements I just wanted a temporary solution so I will mark it as an answer. Afterwards I decided to break the name into two fields, first name and last name, to make it easier to validate.